# Separate date off end of number sequence

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have a lot of numbers: `4498988212174520322014-03-29` like this, which by mistake are a concatenation of a tweet id number and a date.

I was wondering if there a regex that would insert a space before the start of the `2014-03-29` segment?  So I could search for 2014 and then insert a space before this sequence of numbers. I would prefer that it is for notepad++.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: This is a specific task (not well suited for SO) until there is a minimal failing/problematic test case (in which it becomes a problem, which is much better suited). It's also more productive to look at even a minimal test case and analyze why it "didn't work" or behaved unexpectedly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Find: `(.*?)([\d]{4}-[\d]{2}-[\d]{2})`

Replace: `\1 \2`

**References:**

http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Regular_Expressions
http://pnotepad.org/docs/search/regular_expressions/

Comment: I think Notepad++ will prefer `\1 \2`.  Also, would point out there is a space between them (just as you made it ... but in case the reader doesn't observe fully).

Comment: I also use \1 \2, changed that. tks

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing

```
(?=\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}$)
```

with a space.

Explanation and demonstration here: http://regex101.com/r/uM3uN6

Comment: Nice resource cited.  Maybe user3244770 can make that his first stop, next time  :-)